# Connecting markers with PolyLine does not work

Tags: geopandas, folium, shapely

I'm having a geopandas table that looks like:

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
|    |   Score |   LATITUDE |   LONGITUDE | Name   | From   | geometry                       |
|----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------|
|  0 |       9 |    47.0989 |     6.81907 | a      | a      | POINT (6.81906939 47.09885642) |
|  1 |       4 |    47.0993 |     6.82133 | b      | a      | POINT (6.82133392 47.09932583) |
|  2 |      12 |    47.1006 |     6.82169 | c      | a      | POINT (6.821687 47.10058986)   |
|  3 |      12 |    47.1006 |     6.82169 | d      | f      | POINT (6.821687 47.10058986)   |
|  4 |       2 |    47.0985 |     6.81926 | e      | b      | POINT (6.81926344 47.09847967) |
|  5 |       4 |    47.0998 |     6.82126 | f      | b      | POINT (6.82126031 47.09980364) |
|  6 |       2 |    47.0993 |     6.82197 | g      | b      | POINT (6.82197033 47.09929947) |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+--------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

One column shows the `Name` of the datapoints and another column where they come `From`.
Now I want to connect the markers/datapoints with their sources. I tried following code, but it doesn't work:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, df[["Name", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"]],
        on="Name", how="left", suffixes=["_to", "_from"])

latlong_from = zip(df2["LATITUDE_from"], df2["LONGITUDE_from"])
latlong_to = zip(df2["LATITUDE_to"], df2["LONGITUDE_to"])


for _from, _to in zip(latlong_from, latlong_to):
    folium.PolyLine([[_from[0], _from[1]], 
                     [_to[0], _to[1]]]).add_to(m)
    
m
```

It still looks like:

[image]

Does somebody see what I'm droing wrong?

---

**Update**

Now I tried to create a new geopandas-df with only the lines. But they also do not appear.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df2 = pd.merge(df, df[["Name", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"]],
        on="Name", how="left", suffixes=["_to", "_from"])
df2["from_geometry"] = geopandas.points_from_xy(df2["LONGITUDE_from"], df2["LATITUDE_from"])
df2['line'] = df2.apply(lambda row: LineString([row['from_geometry'], row['geometry']]), axis=1) #Create a linestring column

gdf2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df2, 
    geometry=df2["line"])
gdf2.drop(["line", "from_geometry"], axis=1, inplace=True)
gdf2.crs = "EPSG:4326"

gdf2.explore(color="red")
```

For better overview I don't copy again a screenshot. But it zooms to the right area in map, so coords should be fine, but there are no lines. I'm lost, can somebody give a hint? I don't need a properly coded solution, just an idea what I could try or what I'm doing wrong.

---

### Goal

Here an example for expected output:

[image]

### MWE

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd

dict_data = {'Score': {0: 9, 1: 4, 2: 12, 3: 12, 4: 2, 5: 4, 6: 2},
 'LATITUDE': {0: 47.09885642,
  1: 47.09932583,
  2: 47.10058986,
  3: 47.10058986,
  4: 47.09847967,
  5: 47.09980364,
  6: 47.09929947},
 'LONGITUDE': {0: 6.81906939,
  1: 6.82133392,
  2: 6.821687,
  3: 6.821687,
  4: 6.81926344,
  5: 6.82126031,
  6: 6.82197033},
 'Name': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g'},
 'From': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'f', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, 
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df["LONGITUDE"], df["LATITUDE"]))

gdf.crs = "EPSG:4326"

m = gdf.explore(
    column="Name",
    tiles="CartoDB positron",
    cmap="Set1"
)
```

---

**Note:**

*I created a new question, as the old one was to general.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't work out why this does not generate the graph you want. Basically generating a `LineString` for each pair of points defined by pairs of **Name** and **From**

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

gdf2 = gdf.assign(From_point=gdf.set_index("Name").loc[gdf["From"],"geometry"].values)

gdf2["line"] = gdf2[["geometry","From_point"]].apply(LineString, axis=1)

gdf2.set_crs(gdf.crs).set_geometry("line").explore(m=m)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fantastic. I changed "Accepted" to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to add lines with geopandas, but I don't have the knowledge to do so, so I achieved this with folium. The line needs to be specified from point e to point a and from point a to point b, so I manually list the latitude and longitude. That list is then set to a polyline in a loop process.

```
import folium

# line coords
# e -> a:a -> b:b -> f:f -> d:b ->g
line_points = [[[47.098480,6.819263],[47.098856,6.819069]],
[[47.098856,6.819069],[47.099326,6.821334]],
[[47.099326,6.821334],[47.099804,6.821260]],
[[47.099804,6.821260],[47.100590,6.821687]],
[[47.099326,6.821334],[47.099299,6.821970]]]

m = gdf.explore(
    column="Name",
    tiles="CartoDB positron",
    cmap="Set1"
)

for line in line_points:
    #print(line[0][0],line[0][1],line[1][0],line[1][1])
    folium.PolyLine([[line[0][0],line[0][1]],[line[1][0],line[1][1]]], weight=2, color="black").add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I just let it a bit longer open to see if there is a geopandas way to do it. But it works fantastic, vote up.

Comment: PS: just one question, why do you need to import `plugin`?

Comment: The plug-ins were not needed and were removed.